# Embedding another pages register form on my own page?

Tags: php, html

How can I embed another page's register form, to my own page?

The reason why is, I am promoting a company. And I wish to spare the person visiting my page and wanting to sign up, one step in the process.

Instead of having them:

1. Visit my page
2. Get interested in the product
3. Redirecting them to the company's page
4. And then have them to sign up for an account.

I could instead have them:

1. Visit my page
2. Get them interested in the product / company
3. Have them sign up for an account in the company right at my page

As you can see if would benefit both the potential customer and me as a promoter to save the person a step in the process.

So the question is, how can I embed the company's register form 
to my own page / register form.

I've seen a group do this, and know it's possible. 
Now I wish to know how to make this possible and set it up.

I hope I was clear enough. 
Looking forward to hear back from you guys.

Thank's in advance. 
Appreciate it.

/Fredrik

Comment: Have you tried `include()`?

Comment: Set `allow_url_include = 1` and `allow_url_fopen = 1` in php.ini to include an external URL.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to include an external page in your own page, either using IFRAME or by reading page per javascript and including it in a div container. in all terms, you will not end up with a desirable solution and you propably won't be able to include the form only, so you will most likely end up with the complete navigation and other stuff from the customer displayed on your page - could look rather confusing - unless the customer made a "form only" view for you.

A little bit more work and a bit more elegant would be to actually copy the form into your design, so your have your own local form, adapt that to look good on your page and instead of posting to your page you can post the form straight to the customer.

```
<form method="post" action="http://your.customer.com/register.php" target="_blank">
    ... copy mandatory or all fields from customer form ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. The page I am referring to is Dubli.com. 

When a person register for an account directly at their page, they will be redirected to a "thank you for registering. Pease check your e-mail for a confirmation e-mail to start using our service."

I wish to recreate that but directly from my own site. 

1. They visit my site 
2. They register for an account at Dubli.com (directly on my site) 
3. They automatically ge redirected to that very same "thank you page" they would if they registred at Dubli.com

Does this make it even more clear what I'm asking for? :)

Comment: The register form i see there is an overlay, so one more reason to recreate the form on your site. however, if you include dubli.com, then you will have all navigation and surroundings in your container on your page as well. The solution i suggested opens only the "thank you" in a new page, to avoid the navigation problem... you could also post the form using AJAX so in the background you post it to customer and in frontend you display your own "Thank you, you just registered with customer. go visit here..." or whatever.

Comment: I see. Thx a lot for taking the time to explain. I'll have to try this out to see if I get it working. 

I appreciate the help. 
:)